# Python Tkinter, how to get the dictionary automatically updated by a list filled in by entries?

Tags: python, tkinter

**Application:** we are working in a sector where our product can have hundreds of different properties. And when we have to do an offer for tens products, this app could help us to reduce the number of offers by gathering products with the same configuration

**How it works:** user gives the properties in the entries and the application will compare them to see if some configurations are the same (Here configuration = "Config 0", or "Config 1" and so on ...).

The configurations and the given properties should be put in a dictionary-like {Config 1:[1800,1,1500,x...], Config 2:[2000,2,1600,x...], Config n:[x,y,o,x...]} The program will compare the values list of the keys and try to if some values list are the same.

**Problem:** when I put some data in the entries, the dictionary will not be updated.

How can I solve this problem?

The button 'Launch' enables to launch of the comparison

```
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkscrolledframe import ScrolledFrame

data_list=['Name','Q','Speed','TH','Open through','Level','Accesses','CW','CD','CH','SW','SD','Headroom','SP','Door type','DW','DH']
main_list=[]
list_excel=[]
user_entries=[]
user_entries_2=[]
dict_user_entries={}
dict_redundance={}
fenetre =Tk()
fenetre.geometry('800x750')
a = 5

for i in range(a):
    user_entries.append(0)


def test():
    for i in range(len(dict_user_entries)):
        for u in range(3):
            print(dict_user_entries['Config '+str(i)][u].get())

def comparison():
    dict_redundance={}
    print(user_entries[2].get())
    
    for e in range(a):
        for y in range(a):
            dict_user_entries['Config '+str(e)][y]=(user_entries[y].get())
    print(dict_user_entries)   
    for r in range(len(dict_user_entries)):
        for o in range(len(dict_user_entries)):
            if dict_user_entries['Config '+str(r)] == dict_user_entries['Config '+str(o)]:
                print('yes -- Config ',str(r),' = Config ',str(o))
                if  'Config '+str(o) in dict_redundance:
                    dict_redundance['Config '+str(o)].append('Config '+str(r))
                else:
                    dict_redundance['Config '+str(o)]=['Config '+str(r)]
                
            else:
                print('no -- Config ',str(r),' =x= Config ',str(o))
                
    #----- print
    for i in dict_redundance.keys():
        print(i)
        
            

    
cadrebouton=Frame(fenetre)
cadrebouton.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)
boutontest=Button(cadrebouton,text="Test",width=15,height=1,bg="white",bd=5, command=test)
boutontest.pack(side=LEFT, anchor =NW)
boutonlaunch=Button(cadrebouton,text="Launch",width=15,height=1,bg="white",bd=5, command=comparison)
boutonlaunch.pack(side=LEFT, anchor =NW)
    
cadre_global=Frame(fenetre)
cadre_global.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)

cadre_global2=Frame(cadre_global)
cadre_global2.pack(side=LEFT)


for x in range(a):
    frame=Frame(cadre_global2)
    frame.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)
    
    label_data=Label(frame,width=15,text=data_list[x])
    label_data.pack(side=LEFT)
    
cadre_global3=Frame(cadre_global)
cadre_global3.pack(side=LEFT)
bx=0#------Test, to delete

for i in range(5):

    frame2=Frame(cadre_global3)
    frame2.pack(side=LEFT)
    user_entries=[]
    for x in range(a):
        bx+=x
        var_entry=StringVar()
        my_entry=Entry(frame2,textvariable=var_entry, width=15,bd=2)
        my_entry.pack()
        user_entries.append(my_entry)
    dict_user_entries['Config '+str(i)]=[]
    for r in range(a):
        dict_user_entries['Config '+str(i)].append(user_entries[r].get())

    
fenetre.mainloop()

os.system('pause')
```

Thank you!

**EDIT : 10.05.2021** -
I found the solution by myself. I put directly the Entries in the dictionnary without any list between entries and dictionnaries

```
for i in range(nbofconfig):

    frame2=Frame(cadre_global3)
    frame2.pack(side=LEFT)
    dict_user_entries['Config '+str(i)]=[]
    for x in range(a):
        bx+=x
        var_entry=StringVar()
        my_entry=Entry(frame2,textvariable=var_entry, width=15,bd=2)
        my_entry.insert(0,bx)
        my_entry.pack()
        dict_user_entries['Config '+str(i)].append(my_entry)
```

Comment: What is `user_entries` supposed to be? A 5x5 or 1x5 entry matrix? For your posted code, it is a list of 5 entries (the entries in last column).

Comment: Exactly, it's maybe the problem. It's only a 1x5, but it would be better 5x5 but I could not manage it.